# Get value of a href nav-link active

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML code

```html
<a class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-{{key}}-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-{{key}}" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-{{key}}" aria-selected="true" value='{{key}}'>{{key}}</a>
```

and I am trying to get the value of the `value` with jQuery.

I've tried the following:

```js
var selected_key = $(this).find('.nav-link active').attr('value');
```

but it led nowhere. I get undefined as a alert message.

Any ideas? How can I find the class `.nav-link active` and obtain its value attribute?

Comment: try this `$('a.nav-link.active').attr('value');`, & read jQuery

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks!